# Get Array from Array using specific algorithmic logic

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, logic

Let,
an array of length `N`

```
int[]  iArrN=new int[N]{n1,n2,n3....nN};  
//where 1000>N>0 and n1,n2..nN>0(positive integer)
```

i want to take out M element from the array.

```
int[] iArrM=new int[M]{m1,m2...mM};  
//where N>M>0 and m1,m2..mM>0(positive integer)
```

**condition:** sum of the number in `iArraM` must be divisible by `N`

Example here:

```
int[] iArrN=new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}; 
N=5
M=3;
```

then i can get
 `iArrN[1]=2+ iArr[2]=3+ iArr[4]=5=>10%5(N)`

```
int[] iArrM=new int[3]{2,3,5};
```

**To remember:** `N` and `M` can be any number, so we need to find out the logical algorithm for all possible values of N and M.

**What I've tried so far:**
i start from the example.

```
 int[] i=new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

i was thinking about getting all the possible combination with `M` element within this array(`iArrN`)

e.g:

`M=3`

```
i[0],i[1],i[2]==1,2,3
i[0],i[1],i[3]==1,2,4
i[0],i[1],i[4]==1,2,5
i[0],i[2],i[3]==1,3,4
i[0],i[2],i[4]==1,3,5
i[0],i[3],i[4]==1,4,5
..
..
..
and so on.
```

and after getting this we can check the `sum(of the combination)` and `divisibility` with `N`.

how to get this combination using loop or something else.
if you got any easy and suitable solution let me know.

Comment: If you are looking for algorithm SO may not be the best place - at very least clarify what "suitable" solution is (most of such problems have very high O(...) complexity - so one who answers would need to know your boundary)... If you just need code - grab any of "all combinations" questions and just check Sum for condition you need.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a [blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/) that covers how to get all the combinations of a given length for a given set.

Comment: thank you @juharr, let me check it. :)

Comment: @juharr I don't think that article has anything about ensuring that the chosen combination sums to a number divisible by the length of the array.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin No, but that's the easy part. Using Eric's code all you'd have to do is `iArrN.Combinations(M).Where(c => c.Sum() % N == 0);` to get all combinations that meet the condition, or swap `Where` for `FirstOrDefault` if you just need one.

Comment: @juharr That's the sensible way to do it, but probably not the most fun way to do it ;) There's probably a more efficient way to do it using dynamic programming

Comment: yes,i already thought about using linq expression to solve it, but at first i need to find out all possible combination which i mentioned ion my question. that's the hardest part, i'm facing. 
@juharr

Comment: yes, i believe too, there must be any easy solution to solve it.@AsadSaeeduddin

Comment: @عجمان juharr has already linked to an article series that shows you how to do that. Are you having trouble following the steps?

Comment: yes,the link is helpful to produces the combination, but i really don't know,if the `combination'll really help  to solve the problem or not!!!`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach for doing this (as mentioned by juharr in comments) is to simply generate all possible subsets of the input set and filter to find the ones that satisfy the requirement.

Generating all subsets of a given set X is a fairly straightforward recursive algorithm:

1. If X is empty, the only subset is the empty set. END
2. Otherwise, remove some element i from X and recurse to generate all subsets of the resulting set X'
3. The subsets of X are the subsets of X', as well as the sets produced by appending i to the subsets of X'. END

Here's the full implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var result = GenerateSubsets(input)
            .Where(s => s.Sum() % input.Length == 0)
            .ToArray(); // {1, 3}, {4} and {1, 3, 4};
    }

    static IEnumerable<ICollection<T>> GenerateSubsets<T>(ICollection<T> set)
    {
        // Base case
        if (set.Count == 0)
        {
            yield return new T[0];
            yield break;
        }

        // Generate all subsets
        var i = set.First();
        foreach (var subset in GenerateSubsets(set.Except(new[] { i }).ToArray()))
        {
            yield return subset;
            yield return subset.Concat(new[] { i }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array and hash the counts/indexes of `iArrN[i] mod M, i=0 to (N-1)`.

Then generate only combinations that sum to `N` or zero from the keys of the hash. The recursion (or stacked recursion) to generate these combinations can exit early from many of them, thus reducing the number of threads traversed.

If the values `N` or zero are elements in `iArrN`, do not use them in the combination recursion; instead, add them later since we know that any other combination can be added to them without affecting divisibility.

For example:

```
iArrN = {1,2,3,4,5}
hash  = {1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 0:4}; (hash_key = iArrN[hash_value] mod N)

combinations: 1 + 2 + 3, too large ... exit
              1 + 3 + 4, too large ... exit
              1 + 4 works!
              exit 1
              2 + 3 works!
              2 + 4, too large ... exit 
              exit 2
              3 + 4, too large
              exit recursion
```